# Develop my own locale for my locality for windows java

Tags: java, unicode, locale

I am willing to develop my own locale which has different fonts all together... and my locale is not available in the jre provides by default... I came across locale builder of ms and oracle but I couldnot find any download link.. Is it possible to develop my own locale using java from my font file that I have created ?

edited
(the main purpose of my question is I have created my fonts, that works fine when I try to print it in jtextfield.. now I want to display in txt editors like msword or similar.. )any suggestion is helpful..
thank you ..

Comment: Do you need to create your own Fonts or to create your own Locale? Very different things.

Comment: I have my own font I have created.. now what I want to do when I click any key .. my font to be displayed in ms word or something.. for that I found some where I have to develop my own locale..

Comment: I think you're mixing things up. Making a font does not require any programming, nor does installing it into MS Word. If you want to write a Java program that displays your font, that _does_ require some programming but nothing related to locales.

Comment: No as far as I understood .. we have to install the font.. and upon setting the locale ..e.g. japanese we can enter japanese text to the document..

Comment: or changing keyboard layout to japanese .. is it possible to build own keyboard layout .. may be I understood wrong.. if anyone knows how this can be done please suggest